# How to implement SQL subquery in CI 3.x?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have an SQL query like below:

```
SELECT a.name_prov AS prov,city,a.cases 
FROM 
    (SELECT c.name_prov,b.city,a.cases, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.name_prov ORDER BY CAST(a.cases AS INT)DESC) AS rn 
    FROM tb_cases a  
    JOIN tb_city b ON a.id_city = b.id_city 
    JOIN tb_prov c ON a.id_prov = c.id_prov 
    ORDER BY c.name_prov 
    ) a 
ORDER BY a.name_prov,rn
```

How do I write the above select statement in CodeIgniter ver 3.x active record?

Comment: For a query this large without any user inputs, I'd just use $this->db->query($query)->result();

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to look into CodeIgniter forum for this kind of questions.

```php
$subQuery = $this->db->select()
->....
->get_compiled_select();

$this->db->select('*')
->from("($subQuery) as t", false);
```

source: https://forum.codeigniter.com/showthread.php?tid=70943

Also, for the query you provided, you don't need a subquery:

```sql
SELECT c.name_prov as prov, b.city, a.cases, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.name_prov ORDER BY CAST(a.cases AS INT) DESC) AS rn 
FROM tb_cases a  
JOIN tb_city b ON a.id_city = b.id_city 
JOIN tb_prov c ON a.id_prov = c.id_prov
ORDER BY prov, rn
```

this should be equivalent to your query.